# MATCH-based Excel (2007) array formula not iterating over the desired array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I have a long table in excel that maps speed to a list of angles. The angles are 16-bit integers, so `[-180°,180)` corresponds to `[-32768,32768)`.

[image: Sample worksheet 1]

I'm trying to create a reverse map from this data (List of speeds for each angle).

[image: Sample worksheet2]

In order to do this, I have to search each row to see if the angle is present in the speed of that row. I want to list all matches, so in the first column I would have the lowest matching speed, the second column the second lowest, etc.

The array formula I tried was:

```
=SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($AA2,OFFSET($A$3:$A$597,0,3,1,9),0))),$A$3:$A$597,""),1)
```

My hope was that the `OFFSET` function would run for every cell in range `$A$3:$A$597`, but apparently it just does it once. I also tried some shenanigans with concatenation and `CELL("row")`, but got the same result. The `SMALL` function is just so I can select the nth lowest value.

Comment: Can you supplement with the first 5-10 expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array-enter the following into cell `AB2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$597,SMALL(IF($AA2=$D$3:$L$597,ROW($D$3:$L$597)-MIN(ROW($D$3:$L$597))+1,""),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

Then copy over as many columns as you need.

Then copy the range that currently holds these formulas down as far as you need.

Comment: Beautiful. Works perfectly.